# PHP IF function from JSON data

Tags: php

I have the following data, when doing var_dump() on my data:

```
  ["time_zone"]=>
   string(6) "London"
  ["geo_enabled"]=>
   bool(false)
  ["verified"]=>
   bool(true)
```

I can do the following to access the string `"London"`: `$UserTimeZone = $userProfile->time_zone;`

However I also need to be able to determine whether the `"verified"` bool value is true/false.

How can I write an if to check if the `"verified"` bool value is true/false.

I've tried the following and it isn't working it always returns - not verified:

```
$verified->verified;

if ($verified) {
  echo "verified";
} else {
  echo "not verified";
}
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like you are actually setting the variable $verified, in which case it would always result as false in your if statement.

```
$verfied->$verified; // This isn't setting the variable $verified to anything.

$verified = $userProfile->verified; // This sets the variable $verified to what is stored in your user profile object

if ($verified) {
  echo "verified";
} else {
  echo "not verified";
}
```

Or, you could do:

```
if ($userProfile->verified) {
  echo "verified";
} else {
  echo "not verified";
}
```

This way you don't have to worry about setting any extra variables, you're just accessing what is stored in the object.